# Vertical chinese text items float next to label

Tags: html, css

Normally it uses float left to make the second div float next to first div, here is my situation:

```css
.group-header-tags {
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
 float:left;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
}

.group-header-tags .field-label {
    height:50px;
}

.group-header-tags .field-items {
    float:left;
    height:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible group-header-tags field-group-div speed-fast effect-none fieldgroup-effects-processed">
 <h3><span class="field-group-format-toggler"><a class="field-group-format-title" href="#"></a></span></h3>
 <div class="field-group-format-wrapper" style="display: block;">
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-alias field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">別名:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-flavor field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">性味:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-channel field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">歸經:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-function field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">功效:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-cure field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">主治:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[**JsFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/j0xa3rar/1/)

but in chinese vertical text, how can i make "紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角" float next to 別名: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the display of classes : `field`, `field-label` and `field-items` to table and table-cell like this:

```
.field { display: table; }

.field-label{ display: table-cell; float: left; } 

.field-items{ display: table-cell; float: left; }
```

Something like:

```css
.group-header-tags {
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
 float:left;
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
}

.group-header-tags .field-label {
    height:50px;
}

.group-header-tags .field-items {
    float:left;
    height:250px;
}
    
.field {
    display: table;
}
      
.field-label{
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
} 
    
.field-items{
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible group-header-tags field-group-div speed-fast effect-none fieldgroup-effects-processed">
 <h3><span class="field-group-format-toggler"><a class="field-group-format-title" href="#"></a></span></h3>
 <div class="field-group-format-wrapper" style="display: block;">
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-alias field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">別名:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-flavor field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">性味:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-channel field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">歸經:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-function field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">功效:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-herb-cure field-type-text-long field-label-above">
   <div class="field-label">主治:&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">紅龍果、龍珠果，是仙人掌科三角柱屬</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

*I hope this what you need, Thanks.*

Comment: @hkguile My pleasure :)